# when I am trying to upload file using java am getting this error The system cannot find the file specified (tmp)

Tags: java, inputstream, fileinputstream

I am generating a `temp` file in my cash C drive it's only generating one file the second one is not generating and I am getting this error:

> The system cannot find the file specified (tmp)*

```
InputStream inputStrJw = null;
inputStrJw = this.videoLinkEntertainment.getInputstream();
File destFileJw = new File("D:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 9.0\\webapps\\movies\\" + this.gener + "\\" + fileNameVideo);
FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStrJw, destFileJw);
this.GeneratedPath = "D:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 9.0\\webapps\\movies\\" + this.gener + "\\" + fileNameVideo;

inputStrJw.close();

InputStream inputStrJw2 = null;
inputStrJw2 = this.coverImageEntertainment.getInputstream();
File destFileJw2 = new File("D:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 9.0\\webapps\\movies\\" + this.gener + "\\" + fileNameImage);
FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStrJw2, destFileJw2);
this.GeneratedPathForImage = "D:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 9.0\\webapps\\movies\\" + this.gener + "\\" + fileNameImage;

inputStrJw2.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to print all the files within the directory to see if your file is listed

```java
File file = new File(".");
for(String aFile : file.list()) System.out.println(aFile);
```

Comment: it only create 1 temp file in my drive C instead of 2 temp file ! :(